# is there a way to embed a SingleChildScrollView (Vertical) within another SingleChildScrollView(Horizontal) in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my app there is a SingleChildScrollView(with scrollable direction as Horizontal) which has a N number of containers.

Is there a way to embed a the SingleChildScrollView(with scrollable direction as Horizontal) into a SingleChildScrollView (with scrollable direction as Vertical) in Flutter.

for example:

```
class HomeBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: sidePadding,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              HomeAppbar(),
              addVerticalSpace(15),
              Text(
                'Welcome, Jack',
                style: themeData.textTheme.headline1,
              ),
              addVerticalSpace(15),
              SearchField(
                width: mediasize.width - 2 * screenHorizontalPadding,
                height: mediasize.height,
              ),
              addVerticalSpace(25),

//I want to add a SingleChildScrollView (Vertical Direction) from this point to

              TitleMoreBar(barTitle: 'Trending'),
              addVerticalSpace(15),

//the FullProductCardHorizontalList() has a SingleChildScrollView(Horizontal direction)
              FullProductCardHorizontalList(),
              addVerticalSpace(25),
              TitleMoreBar(barTitle: 'Popular Brands'),
              addVerticalSpace(25),

//the BrandCardList() has a SingleChildScrollView(Horizontal direction)
              BrandCardList(),

// this where the SingleChildScrollView (Vertical) should end
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollTraining extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScrollingTraining createState() => _ScrollingTraining();
}

class _ScrollingTraining extends State<ScrollTraining> {
  double mWidth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    mWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: mWidth,
              height: 400,
              color: Colors.indigo,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Fixed Box"),
            ),
            Container(
              width: mWidth,
              height: 200,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: getChildren(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: mWidth,
              height: 400,
              color: Colors.brown,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Fixed Box"),
            ),
            Container(
              width: mWidth,
              height: 200,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: getChildren(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getChildren() {
    List<Widget> output = List();
    List<Color> colorList = [
      Colors.redAccent,
      Colors.deepOrange,
      Colors.orangeAccent,
      Colors.yellow,
      Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      Colors.green,
      Colors.greenAccent,
      Colors.blue,
      Colors.purpleAccent,
      Colors.pink,
    ];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      output.add(Container(
        width: 140,
        height: 200,
        color: colorList[i],
      ));
    }

    return output;
  }
}
```

I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: The example generates the following from top to bottom: one Fixed Sized Box, a SingleChildScrollView(Horizontal) for number of boxes, one Fixed Sized Box and lastly another SingleChildScrollView(Horizontal). All the above 4 Container are in a Column which is then wrapped by a SingleChildScrollView(Vertical). What should I do to make only the last 3 or 2 or 1 to have SingleChildScrollView(Vertical), so that the first 1 or 2 or 3 is fixed? I hope you get my point!

Comment: I cant understand your point! do you want to have more than 1 vertical Scrollview and some horizontal scrollview?

Comment: Instead of SCSV(Vertical)[Container1, SCSV(Horizontal){Container2} , Container3], I want the following : Container1, SCSV(Vertical)[SCSV(Horizontal){Container2} , Container3]

Comment: You can use any combination. It is only better to use the column and row as the child of SCSV for more than one child. like: SCSV(vertical)[Column: [SCSV(horizontal)[Row:[children], & others],];